# File upload large file size (4GB) using MVC C# with pause/resume functionality

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I looking file upload (Max:4GB) functionality in MVC C# application with pause/resume functionality. if any one knows best cheapest thirty party plugin/examples, please let me know. The web config file have key, where i need to upload the files (Not using FTP).
please suggest me where to start?

Thanks
Raja